# does selecting html string with JQuery selector creates html dom element

Tags: jquery

I have following code which gives me SVG element if I am doing $(result), is it creating an HTML element

```
private getSVGImage(imageURL: string) {
        let image: any;
        $.ajax({
            url: imageURL,
            headers: {
                'Cache-Control': 'max-age=3000'
            },
            success: function (result) {
                image = $(result).find('svg')[0]; //todo: check this for memory leak.
            },
            async: false
        });
        return image;
    }
```

I am afraid that I am not leaving any memory leak because of detached dom node

Comment: suggest dont use false in async